# According to PEP8, should variables that have assigned class be lowercased?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I have case like this:

```
Serializer = get_serializer_class()
```

According to PEP8 (or any other newer official style guide) should serializer be a lower case or upper case? Note that `Serializer` is a class, not an instance of a class.

Comment: by convention (which I strongly suggest that you follow ([PEP8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))) the variable names should be lowercase (also called `snake_case`) (as in your case it should be `serializer`) but that is just a convention and it is up to you to follow it or not so this is a bit of an opinionated question which is not really suited for StackOverflow so I am voting to close it

Comment: There are pretty standard conventions for naming things in python, especially if you formulate the question to be "According to PEPs, ...". If you follow PEP8, you would not name your functions `MyFUNCTION()`, and it is not opinion based. Making slight modification to the question and voting to open this again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class names are capitalized by the PEP 8 convention, but this is just a variable name (instance of the class). So the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

PEP 8 states that

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.

So the answer to your question would be no.

Class names however:

> Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.